# How to use measurement protocol for desktop application

Tags: ajax, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

what I have tried is,

[with POST]

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;

$.ajax({
    url : "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-1&cid=e8efa9cb-7b9e-479e-b07b-1528547dcdb4&t=event&ec=UX&ea=click&z=123456",
    type : 'POST',
    cache : false,
    dataType : 'json',
    success:function(data) {
        alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("Failure: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

or [with GET]

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;

$.ajax({
    url : "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-1&cid=e8efa9cb-7b9e-479e-b07b-1528547dcdb4&t=event&ec=UX&ea=click&z=123456",
    dataType : 'json',
    success:function(data) {
        alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("Failure: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

Onclick of button I have added this code.

I'm getting status 200 but, In google analytics report [real time data] its showing No active users.  And if I check previous days report its showing some count for user sessions.

Comment: My ajax is very rusty but are you sure that's how you send a HTTP POST?   Looks more like a HTTP Get with post data tacked on the end like a get.

Comment: request can be send through GET method.  I have updated code.

Comment: probably not related but I am just wondering what is &z= ?   event value is ev=

Comment: try adding el and ev and see what happens.   They shouldn't be required.

Comment: I ran it thought he debugger and your quest is fine.  However remember by the looks of it you are only sending the event.   if you want to see screen or page then you are going to have to send more data then that.

Comment: z for avoiding caching.

Comment: but atleast I should get active user count in report page, irrespect of screen or page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99914/discussion-between-divesh-oswal-and-daimto).

Comment: Logged it as an issue https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=848&thanks=848&ts=1452075871

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in the way the measurement protocol is handling events.  I have created an issue for this Here:   [Issue 848:  Events not showing up on Real-time reports](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=848&thanks=848&ts=1452075871)

You don't send the Application variables the data will not be displayed in real-time reports.   As soon as you send a request with it they pop up again but you loose them if you send another event without it.   It is not document at this time that the application variables are required.   Also a debug on your request comes back with valid hit data.

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect?v=1&tid=UA-xxxxx-1&cid=e8efa9cb-7b9e-479e-b07b-1528547dcdb4&t=event&ec=UX&ea=click&z=123456

{
  "hitParsingResult": [ {
    "valid": true,
    "parserMessage": [ ],
    "hit": "/debug/collect?v=1\u0026tid=UA-xxxxx-1\u0026cid=e8efa9cb-7b9e-479e-b07b-1528547dcdb4\u0026t=event\u0026ec=UX\u0026ea=click\u0026z=123456"
  } ],
  "parserMessage": [ {
    "messageType": "INFO",
    "description": "Found 1 hit in the request."
  } ]
}
```

**Solution / work around:**

Add the following items to your request should fix the problem. Again at this time it is not documented that they are required.  However my testing has shown when you send these everything appears correctly again in the real-time reports.

```
cd=ScreenName&an=ApplicationName&aid=ApplicationId&av=3.0&ai‌​id=1.0
```

Comment: Update: I have heard from Google they are looking into it.   It is unclear if its an issue with real-time reports or standard reports.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not a technical issue, but a data compatibility issue.
The CID you used doesn't seem to fit GA structure of cid, which is **[10 digits][dot][10 digits]**, i.e. **1234567890.1234567890**
Try to force a different ID to check my solution.

Comment: how to generate cid?

Comment: I have tested it this is a bug.  Not related to CID CID can be anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

What possible problems do you have:

1. Hope "UA-XXXXXXXX-1" - it is just for code example and you are using "real" GA ID in your code.
2. Regarding ClientID: in the [GA docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#clientId) you may see ClientID like '35009a79-1a05-49d7-b876-2b884d0f825b'. But this ClientID should match for some ClientIDs for website users, that visited your website. Without specific settings GA will not generate ClientID like '35009a79-1a05-49d7-b876-2b884d0f825b', as GA automatically generates ClientID in format XXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX, like "1068584379.1447331221".

How to find ClientID manually: find "_ga" cookie for your website, it should looks like "GA1.2.1068584379.1447331221". ClientID is **1068584379.1447331221** in this cookie.

How to get this parameter in JS-srcipt:

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
});
```

Remember, that ClientID identifies each unique user(browser) and ties user data, sent by measurement protocol, with user data, collected on a client-side(by GA js library). So to see data(sent by Measurement Protocol) in the GA reports is preferable to use "real" ClientID, for user, that visited website in the past.